# How to create dashed lines in terminal for indentation

Tags: vim, terminal

I'm using vim in Mac terminal. I want to have dashed lines in front of each line to indicate the tabs and indentations. Is there a way to configure this in .vimrc? The editor shown in the picture is sharelatex.

[image]

Many thanks!

Comment: See `:help 'list'` and `:help 'listchars'`.

Answer (score 3):

Set `listchars` to that symbol (you might want one of these: `¦⁞⋮┆┊┋┇︙⸽`) and a space:

```
set listchars=tab:¦\
```

That is "tab", followed by a colon, your desired character, a backslash **and a space**.
In addition, to see the effect, you have to set the `list` option:

```
set list
```

[image]

---

`listchars` can be used to set more characters to show in special places, e.g. `eol` to show a character at the end of a line, or `trail` to see trailing spaces. To set multiple ones, seperate them by commas:

```
set listchars=tab:¦\ ,trail:·
```